# How to save all images embedded in email in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, images, thunderbird, extract

In Thunderbird, how to save all images embedded (`multipart/related` MIME format) in email in one turn?

Answer (score 33):

Select `View > Show As/Message Body As > Plain text` and all embedded content
will become attachments. Now right-click on attachments pane, and select `Save All`

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. This possibly might have to do with versions, I hope, versions from nowadays will show the text version of the email, if one is available. In my case, the text version of the message has different content. :-(

Comment: Works for me thanks! On newer versions (I'm on 60.0) you need to press alt key first to see view option.

Comment: Trys to save everything as "image.jpg, overwrites each other.

Comment: Works for me on Thunderbird 68.10.0 (64-bit) Linux. The attachments widget is at the bottom of the email.

Comment: Does only work for images, that are attached to the email and embedded by a relative path. It does not work for images, that are embedded via web URL.

Answer (score 8):

Another option under Debian or Ubuntu is

1. Save the mail to disk as `email.eml`.
2. Open up a terminal and navigate to the directory where you saved the mail to
3. `sudo apt install mpack`
4. `munpack email.eml`

Afterwards, all attached files or embedded images should be as single files in the current directory.
For other linuxes, `mpack` should be available from the respective repository.

Comment: Press Alt key. Then you will see more options at the top of the window. Checked on newest Thunderbird currently available (60.0 32-bit). Then go View > Message Body As > Plain text. As mentioned above right-click on attachments pane, and select Save All

Comment: Thanks @Gunnm, I proposed an edit to the top answer. I'll leave this here though, maybe it comes in handy for someone who only has an `*.eml` file.

Comment: @Mitja Thanks for your answer, latest Thunderbird doesn't show inline images as attachments when showing message body as plain text, I can only see [image] [image] [image] in the text...